# How to, provide URL parameters using github-flask for {+path}?

Tags: python, api, github, flask, keyword-argument

First, I am a total n00b to Python. I am using github-flask, and flask obviously, to pull data from the GitHub API. I am trying to use the `contents_url` and retrieve a file. The URL from the GitHub API is something like:

```
// json
{
    ...
    "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/<org_name>/<repo_name>/contents/{+path}"
    ...
}
```

... and when I try and give that to the github-flask instance I get a TypeError, "TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'" using:

```
# python
contents = github.get(repo['contents_url'], path='.gitignore')
```

I'm pretty sure I am missing something simple. I don't have to resort to string manipulation do I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's recommended string interpolation is the `.format` method. Your code will work with that with just a few minor changes:

```
contents = github.get(repo['contents_url'].format(path='.gitignore'))
```

But you'll also have to change your `contents_url` slightly:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<org_name>/<repo_name>/contents/{path}
```

Just be careful - `.format` interpolates based on curly braces, so any literal curly braces need to be escaped. More information is available here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

---

Edit: As you mentioned in the comment below, the URL is coming directly from GitHub's API and you can't/shouldn't change it. It turns out they're using [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) URL templates (see https://developer.github.com/v3/#hypermedia). If you use the [uritemplate](https://github.com/uri-templates/uritemplate-py) library I suggested below, the code will look like this:

```
from uritemplate import expand

# ...

contents = github.get(expand(repo['contents_url'], {'path': '.gitignore'}))
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't - or shouldn't - change the `contents_url` because it is provided by the GitHub API as a string. I was hoping to be able to simply use it.

Comment: It looks at if the GitHub API is using [RFC 6570](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6570) URL templates (see https://developer.github.com/v3/#hypermedia). You'll want to use an appropriate library. It looks like [uritemplate](https://github.com/uri-templates/uritemplate-py) may be the best one to start with.

Comment: I haven't yet had a chance to try this out but it sounds good. I will try and get to it soon.